# PHP can't access file due to read only permissions

Tags: php, windows

I want to open, read, and modify a file. However, the file's current path puts it in folders that are read only. Meaning that when I open it with PHP, the file can be read but not modified. When I try to move the file to a folder in my User path, the PHP script can't find it.

Since moving the file into my User path is my best guess at a solution, does anyone know how to make PHP find the file once its there? (or why it isn't currently)

Any help is appreciated.

Example code (finding an mdb file, can read but not write):

```
<?php
    $dbName = "C:/db/SampleUsers.accdb";
    $connection = odbc_pconnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" .$dbName, ";", ";");
    if ($connection != true){ exit; };
    odbc_close ( $connection );
    echo ": works :";
?>
```

Example code (finding an mdb file, have permission to folder but the file will not be found)

```
<?php
    $dbName = "C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Project6\db\SampleUsers.accdb";
    $connection = odbc_pconnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" .$dbName, ";", ";");
    if ($connection != true){ exit; };
    odbc_close ( $connection );
    echo ": works :";
?>
```

Comment: change its permissions, or move it, you seem to know the answer already

Comment: I can't change the permissions, it resets whenever I do. I've tried going through the top level folder, and giving myself ownership. Through other posts, it seems like my company is running software on the computer that will not allow me to change the read-only property even though I have admin rights.
If I move the file to my user path (ex: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Project6\db\SampleUsers.accdb") then the PHP won't even connect as read only.

Comment: Could it be ODBC itself setting the file to read-only as Access databases are single-user and not designed for web-apps? https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_to_Microsoft_Access . This might be related: "If you will connect with a File DSN, you cannot use it directly, but you need an additional ADO connection string. The database tables will be readonly in this case."

Comment: Why are your using backslashs in the second example? If your first code worked with forward slashes your second should too. Just something I think may be an issue. Not familiar with Microsoft in this fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the file's content, storing it into a variable, then saving the contents in another file in a directory you have permission.

Comment: I can't do this without having a directory that PHP can use. I have permission for my User folder, but for some reason PHP can't access files from there.